# enhancedList oncomplete not running from component

Tags: visualforce-component, enhancedlist

The "oncomplete" event on enhancedLists should fire when the list is loaded. This works as expected when the enhancedList is on a VF page but not on a VF component.

Am I missing something or is this appearing to be a bug?

VF page (alert shows when page is loaded):

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:enhancedList type="Contact" height="600" oncomplete="alert('x');"/>
</apex:page>
```

VF component (alert does not show when component is included in a page):

```
<apex:component>
    <apex:enhancedList type="Contact" height="600" oncomplete="alert('x');"/>
</apex:component>
```

Comment: What happens once you place that component inside visualforce page ? apex: component eventually goes inside a vf page?